# Display SQL for worksheet in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

How can I display SQL/MDX query to the DB based on result on worksheet? For example I created one aggregated table in worksheet in Tableau and then I have to use the same SQL statement to stored procedure which display the same view (table). Where I will find this query?

Answer (score 2):

You can run the Tableau Performance Recorder via the Help menu to record timing, events and queries. After you stop recording, you'll get a workbook pop up where you can examine the recorded info, including SQL queries.

Long queries may not fit in the space provided in the performance workbook, so it can appear as if the query may be truncated. But if you copy and paste into another window, you can see all the query - so it isn't really truncated other than for display purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access that information from within Tableau - you have to run a profiler trace log or look at the log files generated by Tableau.

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/viewing-underlying-sql-queries-desktop

> Option 1: Use the Performance Recording Feature For more information,
>   see Create a Performance Recording and Interpret a Performance
>   Recording Workbook in Tableau Help. Option 2: Review the Tableau
>   Desktop Logs Navigate to the Logs folder inside the My Tableau
>   Repository folder.  By default, the My Tableau Repository can be found
>   inside the My Documents folder on Windows or the Documents folder on a
>   Mac. If you have a live connection to the data source, check the
>   log.txt and tabprotosrv.txt files. If you are using an extract, check
>   the tdeserver.txt file. The tabprotosrv.txt file often shows detailed
>   information about queries.